# Returning values through a Dialog

Tags: android

I currently have a method which should return the result of a dialog. The code I am using is

```
 private int ShowDialog(String FileName)
 {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      // set title
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Play File");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Would you like .... file")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        return 1;
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        return 0;
                    }
                });

             AlertDialog alert11 = alertDialogBuilder.create();
             alert11.show();

 }
```

But it seems like the onClick method should be a void. Is there anyway by which I can make this method return a value and in return cause the ShowDialog method to return that value.?

Comment: "method which should return the result of a dialog" can you tell specifically what result of dialog you want to return

Comment: What do you want to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
private int ShowDialog(String FileName)
{
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     // set title
     alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Play File");

           // set dialog message
           alertDialogBuilder
               .setMessage("Would you like .... file")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                   {
                       returnVal = 1;  // Instead of directly returning - set it here
                       dialog.dismiss();

                   }
                 })
               .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                       returnVal = 0;  // Instead of directly returning - set it here
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });

            AlertDialog alert11 = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert11.show();

     return returnVal; // return it here.
}
```

Here `returnVal` is a member variable in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Dialogs are sort of asynchronous, which means that your method can only show it, but the actual value of the dialog will only be known until the user presses a button. You need change your code to fit this. You can call another method in the container class once the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick()` method of a button on the `AlertDialog` is invoked by the system on a separate thread. And as you can see the return type of the method is `void`, you cannot return any values as such.

What you can do is to use a `Handler` and invoke a method on your class and pass any values that you may need.